# footnote and autocite=footnote don't behave the same under fnpct

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, babel, french

This may sound like a crazy scenario, but whilst using `fnpct` (and the `after-punct-space` option especially) and the `\autocite` command from `biblatex` (using the option `autocite=footnote`), I realized the spacing around the footnote mark wasn't treated the same way as with the command `\footnote`. This is hardly noticeable in `british`, but very severe in `french` (from `babel`). A weird thing is that it is `\footnote` that doesn't seem to react to the `after-punct-space` option when `french` is the language, whereas `\autocite` does.

I'm using v2.8a of `biblatex` and `fnpct` v0.2k (2013/04/07).

Variants I tried:

- neither `\frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false}` nor 
  `\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}` help
- not using anything from `biblatex` at all (`footnote` is still problematic)

I'd be satisfied if I could redefine the basic `\footnote` like it's `autocite=footnote` version, but I'm not savvy enough to know how to dig that information up.

Here's a code example, tuned for maximal graphical effect (the right alignment just helps visualize things, for example):

```
\documentclass[french,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fnpct}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[autocite=footnote,autopunct=false]{biblatex}

\AdaptNoteOptNoMult\autocite

\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{6cm}
\emph{Without \texttt{after-punct-space}:}
\begin{flushright}

Here I'm using footnote\footnote[2]{Check!}.

\setcounter{mpfootnote}{1}

And here\ldots\ autocite\autocite{nokeyneeded}.
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\vspace*{1cm}

\setfnpct{after-punct-space=-1em}

\begin{minipage}{6cm}
\emph{With \texttt{after-punct-space}:}
\begin{flushright}
Here I'm using footnote\footnote[2]{Check!}.

\setcounter{mpfootnote}{1}

And here\ldots\ autocite\autocite{nokeyneeded}.
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[edited to add the `fnpct` package version]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've discovered two different and unrelated issues:

1. The language definition file for French, `frenchb.ldf`, makes the following definitions at begin document:

   ```
   \let\@footnotemarkORI\@footnotemark
   \def\@footnotemarkFB{\leavevmode\unskip\unkern
                        \,\@footnotemarkORI}%
   ```

   This disables `fnpct`'s own adaptions. Since `fnpct` has the means to set all those spaces around footnote marks in different situations the definition from `frenchb-ldf` isn't really needed and can be reverted again after begin document:

   ```
   \begin{document}
   \makeatletter
   \let\@footnotemark\@footnotemarkORI
   \makeatother
   ```
2. The issue with `\autocite` is quite different. Here, `fnpct`'s mechansim strikes back: `\auocite` eventually inserts `\footnote` which has also been redefined by `fnpct`. That use of `\footnote` does not find a trailing punctuation and assumes it comes after a word. This is why it inserts the `before-footnote-space` which is what you're seeing.  The following example amplifies this:

   ```
   \documentclass[12pt]{article}

   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{fnpct}
   \usepackage[autocite=footnote,autopunct=false]{biblatex}

   \renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}

   \AdaptNoteOptNoMult\autocite

   \begin{document}

   \begin{minipage}{6cm}
   \begin{flushright}
     Here I'm using footnote\footnote[2]{Check!}.\par
     \setcounter{mpfootnote}{1}
     And here\ldots\ autocite\autocite{nokeyneeded}.\par
     \setcounter{mpfootnote}{1}
     \setfnpct{before-footnote-space=.5em}
     And here\ldots\ autocite\autocite{nokeyneeded}.\par
   \end{flushright}
   \end{minipage}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   There is no easy fix other than setting

   ```
   \setfnpct{before-footnote-space=0pt}
   ```

I will certainly fix issue 2 in `fnpct` (I already have fixed it in my development version). I'll probably also undo `frenchb.ldf`'s redefinition of `\@footnotemark` when `fnpct` is loaded and instead adapt the `before-footnote-space` accordingly when French is the main document language.

---

Both issues are fixed in `fnpct` v0.4a 2013/12/23:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fnpct}[2013/12/23]
\usepackage[autocite=footnote,autopunct=false]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}

\AdaptNoteOptNoMult\autocite

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{6cm}
\begin{flushright}
  Here I'm using footnote\footnote[2]{Check!}.\par
  \setcounter{mpfootnote}{1}
  And here\ldots\ autocite\autocite{nokeyneeded}.\par
  \setcounter{mpfootnote}{1}
  Text\footnote{foo} text
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ChristophB. you're welcome :)

Comment: @ChristophB. both issues are fixed in v0.4a